# Google Ad on site overflowing to beige background

Tags: javascript, html, css, adsense

I have a responsive google Ad on my website and sometimes (depending on the Ad) the ad will stop and then overflow to a beige background (see image).

I know I can put it in a div tag and limit the width to decrease the chances of this happening, as right now it is allowed to span 100% the width of my site. But I was hoping for a way to change the background color to black or whatever the cleanest method is. Any tips? advice? thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears like you're forcing it to use 100% of the width. Did you try (in your CSS file):

```
max-width: 100%;
```

instead of

```
width: 100%;
```

If that doesn't work, then also try [this solution](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!msg/adsense/UhGuUfdpJfI/d4hovPC3wK8J):

```
ins.adsbygoogle {
  background-color: transparent !important;
}
```

Comment: thanks! the div had to be 100% forced due to formatting, but the second solution works perfectly!